# Sqlite does not retrieve data when applied condition

Tags: android

I stored the data in sqllite. When I am retrieving the data from the database using sql query with where clause. It does not give any result. I check even it must return two records.

**Data in Database**

```
exercise_main_muscle=Biceps exercise_equipment=Dumbbell exercise_name=Incline Dumbbell Curl exercise_mechanic=Isolation exercise_other_muscle=Forearms exercise_level=Beginner exercise_type=Strength

exercise_main_muscle=Biceps exercise_equipment=Dumbbell exercise_name=Hammer Curl exercise_mechanic=Isolation exercise_other_muscle=Forearms exercise_level=Beginner exercise_type=Strength`
```

Using this query :

```
select * from exercise where exercise_type = 'Strength' AND exercise_main_muscle = 'Biceps' AND exercise_other_muscle = 'Forearms' AND exercise_equipment = 'Isolation' AND exercise_mechanic = 'Beginner'
```

Code:

```
String sql = "select * from " + TABLE_EXERCISE + " where " + KEY_EXERCISE_TYPE + " = '" + exerciseType + "' AND "
                + KEY_MAIN_MUSCLE + " = '" + mainMuscle + "' AND " + KEY_OTHER_MUSCLE + " = '" + otherMuscle + "' AND "
                + KEY_EXERCISE_EQUIPMENT + " = '" + equipment + "' AND " + KEY_MECHANIC + " = '" + mechanic + "'";

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

cursor.moveToFirst();

while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    Exercise exercise = cursorToExercise(cursor);
    exerciseList.add(exercise);
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
db.close();

private Exercise cursorToExercise(Cursor cursor) {
    Exercise exercise = new Exercise();
    exercise.setID(cursor.getLong(0));
    exercise.setExerciseName(cursor.getString(1));
    exercise.setExerciseType(cursor.getString(2));
    exercise.setMainMuscle(cursor.getString(3));
    exercise.setOtherMuscle(cursor.getString(4));
    exercise.setExerciseEquipment(cursor.getString(5));
    exercise.setExerciseMechanic(cursor.getString(6));
    exercise.setExerciseLevel(cursor.getString(7));
    return exercise;
}
```

Comment: Try to print out the size of cursor first in your logcat. If possible post some more code. What is `Exercise exercise = cursorToExercise(cursor);` `Exercise` ?

Comment: Size of cursor is 0. But is should be 2. Please help me what is wrong in the query

Comment: @GrIsHu I have updated

Comment: log cat................

Comment: @Mohit No error logcat..There is no exception thrown

Comment: then there is no data

Comment: one suggestion run on pull database and run query on it check the output

Comment: Yes..No Data when i use where clause. If i remove the where cluase then data appear

Comment: @user2580525 Add this line after query: `Log.i("TESTING", "Rows returned: " + cursor.getCount())` , and see how many rows the query selects.

Comment: It giving 0 when i add the where clause and i remove the where clause then it return 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data in database is `exercise_mechanic=Isolation`

while

your query is `exercise_equipment=Isolation`

```
exercise_mechanic = 'Beginner'
```

Your query is wrong. S